# Unable to setup UITableView cell programatically - thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: swift

I am trying to setup my UITableView cell programmatically using auto layout but it keeps crashing and I am not sure why this is happening.  Please could someone advise?

I am trying to setup my UITableView cell programmatically using auto layout but it keeps crashing and I am not sure why this is happening.  Please could someone advise?

```
class FolderCell: UITableViewCell{

var jTitle: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    return label
}()

var date: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    return label
}()

var aTitle: UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    return label
}

var authors: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    return label
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    cellSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


private func cellSetup(){
    contentView.addSubview(jTitle)
    contentView.addSubview(aTitle)
    contentView.addSubview(date)
    contentView.addSubview(authors)

    setUpLabels()
}

private func setUpLabels(){
    jTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    jTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    jTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    jTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    aTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    aTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: jTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    aTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    aTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true 
}
```

}

I am getting the following crash :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you didn't initiate the aTitle label. Try to initiate it before you use it.

```
 var aTitle: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    return label
}()
```